# how to get {{var return_address}} in magento rma email template

Tags: magento

In RMA email template magento defined Return Address as {{var return_address}}.

Can anyone help me to know from where Magento set this value in email?

Comment: I think these are email variables.Find the email send function like $emailTemplate->send() function.they are set before this send function.

Answer (score 0):

The return address pulls from the address listed as the "Store Information" found in the admin area at"

```
System > Configuration > General > Store Information
```

Once you're on the general tab in the admin area, store information is listed at the bottom.

You can change your store views if you have more than one and see the different addresses associated with each store.